# Different result on .gitignore

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

Following [Version Control with Git 2nd ed](http://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-alias=aps&tag=isdi02-20&link_code=wql&_encoding=UTF-8&field-keywords=9781449316389), not getting same results as book is showing. Am I missing something? This is example from the book.

```
$ cd /tmp/my_stuff
$ git init
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
$ echo "New data" > data
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
# (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
# data
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)


# Manually create an example junk file
$ touch main.o
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
# (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
# data
# main.o
$ echo main.o > .gitignore
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
# (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
# .gitignore
# data
```

But for me after `echo main.o > .gitignore`, `git status` is showing that  `main.o` is not ignored, and is showing in untracked files.

EDIT: In this example there is no commits so `git rm -r --cached .`, is giving me `fatal: pathspec '.' did not match any files`. I have also tried commiting `data`, and `main.o`, then

```
>>touch .gitignore
>>git rm -r --cached .
>>git add .
>>git commit -m ".gitignore is stil not ignoring main.o"
```

Comment: Try clearing your project's cache. 
`git rm -r --cached .`

Comment: Please, show `.gitignore` file content

Comment: `$ echo main.o > .gitignore` is creating `.gitingore` with `main.o` as a file content. I have also made edit to question, to reflect what have I tried so far.

Comment: @That_User The example from book looks alright, can you tell the exact contents of `.gitignore` on your system (do `cat .gitignore`) and also confirm that you have created the `.gitignore` inside the project root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `.gitignore` is created at the same level as the `main.o`, without typo ([your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975623/different-result-on-gitignore#comment38824556_24975623), for instance, mentions `.gitingore` instead of `.gitignore`.

If `main.o` wasn't added (no `git add`), the effect would be instantaneous (no need to even add `.gitignore` to the index or to commit it): the `main.o` file would be ignored in the next `git status` call.

Make sure 'main.o' has no trailing space in its name ('name.o '), or try using more global patterns in the `.gitignore`, to see if that has any effect:

```
*.o
*.o*
```